# How do I remove the unnecessary header on top of onMaster Detail Page with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I am trying to develop an application with MasterDetailPage. But I came into a problem, whichever page I go to, there is always this blue header that put an unnecessary padding into my application. Is there anyway for me to get rid of it?

Thank you so much, I appreciate any help/advice I can get.

[image: The unnecessary blue bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```